RVIZ2 doesnt detect one of the joint/link combos in the URDF while other URDF viewers do
I'm using ROS Jazzy on Ubuntu 24.04. I have a URDF file written with the help of xacro:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot name="my_robot" xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">

  <xacro:include filename="macros.xacro"/>

  <link name="world"></link>

  <joint name="base_joint" type="fixed">
    <origin xyz="1.5 1 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <parent link="world"/>
    <child link="base_link"/>
  </joint>

  <link name="base_link">
    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0.05" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="2.5 1.5 0.1"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="green"/>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0.05" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="2.5 1.5 0.1"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <xacro:inertial_box mass="12" x="2.5" y="1.5" z="0.1">
      <origin xyz="0 0 0.05" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    </xacro:inertial_box>
  </link>
  
  <joint name="slider_joint" type="prismatic">
    <origin xyz="-1.25 0 0.1" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="slider_link"/>
    <axis xyz="1 0 0"/>
    <limit lower="0" upper="2" velocity="100" effort="100"/>
  </joint>

  <link name="slider_link">
    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0.075" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
          <box size="0.5 0.25 0.15"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="blue"/>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0.075" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
          <box size="0.5 0.25 0.15"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <xacro:inertial_box mass="0.5" x="0.5" y="0.25" z="0.15">
      <origin xyz="0 0 0.075" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    </xacro:inertial_box>
  </link>

  <joint name="arm_joint" type="revolute">
    <origin xyz="0.25 0 0.15" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <parent link="slider_link"/>
    <child link="arm_link"/>
    <axis xyz="0 -1 0"/>
    <limit lower="0" upper="${pi/2}" velocity="100" effort="100"/>
  </joint>

  <xacro:property name="arm_length" value="1"/>
  <xacro:property name="arm_radius" value="0.1"/>
  <link name="arm_link">
    <visual>
      <origin xyz="${arm_length/2} 0 0" rpy="0 ${pi/2} 0"/>
      <geometry>                
          <cylinder length="${arm_length}" radius="${arm_radius}"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="orange"/>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin xyz="${arm_length/2} 0 0" rpy="0 ${pi/2} 0"/>
      <geometry>                
          <cylinder length="${arm_length}" radius="${arm_radius}"/>
      </geometry>      
    </collision>
    <xacro:inertial_cylinder mass="1.0" length="${arm_length}" radius="${arm_radius}">
      <origin xyz="${arm_length/2} 0 0 " rpy="0 ${pi/2} 0"/>
    </xacro:inertial_cylinder>
  </link>

  <joint name="camera_joint" type="fixed">
        <origin xyz="${arm_length} 0 ${arm_radius + 0.075}"/>
        <parent link="arm_link"/>
        <child link="camera_link"/>        
  </joint>

  <link name="camera_link">
    <visual>
      <origin xyz="-0.03 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.06 0.15 0.15" />
      </geometry>
      <material name="white"/>
    </visual>
    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0.03 0 0" rpy="0 ${pi/2} 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="0.06" radius="0.04"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="blue"/>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin xyz="0.0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.12 0.15 0.15"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <xacro:inertial_box mass="0.1" x="0.12" y="0.15" z="0.15">
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    </xacro:inertial_box>
  </link>

</robot>

This is the macros.xacro file:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">
  
  <!-- inertial calculations from wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_moments_of_inertia-->

  <xacro:macro name="inertial_sphere" params="mass radius *origin">
    <inertial>
      <xacro:insert_block name="origin"/>
      <mass value="${mass}"/>
  <inertia ixx="${(2/5) * mass * radius*radius}" ixy="0" ixz="0"
               iyy="${(2/5) * mass * radius*radius}" iyz="0"
           izz="${(2/5) * mass * radius*radius}"
      />
    </inertial>
  </xacro:macro>

  <xacro:macro name="inertial_box" params="mass x y z *origin">
    <inertial>
      <xacro:insert_block name="origin"/>
      <mass value="${mass}"/>
  <inertia ixx="${(1/12) * mass * (y*y + z*z)}" ixy="0" ixz="0"
               iyy="${(1/12) * mass * (x*x + z*z)}" iyz="0"
           izz="${(1/12) * mass * (x*x + y*y)}"
      />
    </inertial>
  </xacro:macro>

  <xacro:macro name="inertial_cylinder" params="mass length radius *origin">
    <inertial>
      <xacro:insert_block name="origin"/>
      <mass value="${mass}"/>
  <inertia ixx="${(1/12) * mass * (3*radius*radius + length*length)}" ixy="0" ixz="0"
               iyy="${(1/12) * mass * (3*radius*radius + length*length)}" iyz="0"
           izz="${(1/12) * mass * (3*radius*radius + length*length)}"
      />
    </inertial>
  </xacro:macro>


  <!-- colours -->

  <material name="green">
    <color rgba="0.2 1 0.2 1"/>
  </material>

  <material name="white">
    <color rgba="1 1 1 1"/>
  </material>

  <material name="orange">
    <color rgba="1 0.3 0.1 1"/>
  </material>

  <material name="blue">
    <color rgba="0.2 0.2 1 1"/>
  </material>


</robot>

Viewing this urdf using a VSCode extension works perfectly as expected:

But, in rviz i get the following error:

I suspect it may have something to do with rviz not recognizing the prismatic joint? But that is just a baseless suspicion i have no idea.
I tried exporting the output of xacro to a file to see if it was an xacro issue, but it wasnt.
Furthermore running an echo on the topic shows this:
❯ ros2 topic echo /tf_static
transforms:
- header:
    stamp:
      sec: 1734623986
      nanosec: 111655170
    frame_id: world
  child_frame_id: base_link
  transform:
    translation:
      x: 1.5
      y: 1.0
      z: 0.0
    rotation:
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
      w: 1.0
- header:
    stamp:
      sec: 1734623986
      nanosec: 111655170
    frame_id: arm_link
  child_frame_id: camera_link
  transform:
    translation:
      x: 1.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.175
    rotation:
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
      w: 1.0
---


The error in rviz tells you that it can't render the link because it's missing the transform. Without that transform to know the position it won't render. And the transform usually is provided by the robot state publisher using joint states as it's inputs. This sort is error usually caused by the parent joint state not being published.
It renders in urdf viewers because they just use the default joint position, whereas rviz won't make assumptions about the current pose.

right makes sense, and from the ros echo it looks like only the world frame and arm frame are being published. Exporting the tf tree shows the same. How do i go about debugging why this is happening?

I figured out the problem. When i set my joints to static, RVIZ worked well because it didnt need any joint states.
For joints like prismatic/revolute, I just published some data to the topic joint_states
